# MySQL AUTO_INCREMENT=535

Tags: mysql, innodb, auto-increment

What does `AUTO_INCREMENT=535` actually mean or do? I have seen this used when creating tables as shown below, but never knew what it does or is used for.
Create Table:

```
CREATE TABLE `my_table` (
`entry_id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
`address` varchar(512) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY(entry_id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=535 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Comment: it starts the auto_increment value at 535 instead of the default of 1

Comment: Thanks serakfalcon and sbrbot. So does that mean that my first ebtry_id will actually be 535, and the table cannot allow any entry_id values below that number since it will only increment from there?

Comment: no, you can have any value that would be valid for an `int(11)` as an entry_id (even negative values). Note if you custom insert a value higher than the current highest auto_increment value, you may run into problems (although when you restart the mysql service, it will autoincrement from the highest value in that field).

Answer (score 2):

**Auto increment** field allow automatic indexing of the records in a table. Usually serving as a [Unique Key](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unique_key)

Any table with definition like  `AUTO_INCREMENT=535` would mean that next auto-generated key will start from the 535.

This usually happen when you take **backup from existing database**. But also can be used in some special cases to have higher value of starting index.

Answer (score 1):

Tells when to start with auto_increment counting. For example if you want to reserve some number of ID for some dedicated purposes.

Answer (score 1):

The AUTO_INCREMENT attribute can be used to generate a unique identity

You can use a pair of statements: **DROP TABLE** and **CREATE TABLE** to reset the auto-increment column. Like the **TRUNCATE TABLE** statement, those statements removes all the data and reset the auto-increment value to zero.

*No value was specified for the AUTO_INCREMENT column, so MySQL assigned sequence numbers automatically.*

You can also ** explicitly assign 0 ** to the column to generate sequence numbers. If the column is declared NOT NULL, it is also ** possible to assign NULL ** to the column to generate sequence numbers.

*You can retrieve the most recent AUTO_INCREMENT value with the LAST_INSERT_ID()*

To start with an AUTO_INCREMENT value other than 1, you can set that value with CREATE TABLE or ALTER TABLE, like  this:

```
mysql> ALTER TABLE tbl AUTO_INCREMENT = 100;
```

The **AUTO INCREMENT** interval value is controlled by the MySQL Server variable auto_increment_increment and applies globally. To change this to a number different from the default of 1, use the following command in MySQL:

mysql> SET @@auto_increment_increment = [interval number];

where [interval number] is the interval value you want to use. So, if we want to set the interval to be 5, we would issue the following command:

```
mysql> SET @@auto_increment_increment = 5;
```

refrence:-

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-auto-increment.html